# Определить какая страница использует определенный шаблон wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Нужно определить какая страница используют определенный шаблон wordpress и вывести ее адрес.

Да, есть функция `is_page_template()`, но она проверяет текущую страницу. 

Есть ли какой изящный способ?

Answer (score 0):

Название шаблона WordPress, используемого на странице, хранится в метаданных.
Этот код получает данные о всех страницах, извлекает мета _wp_page_template, сравнивает с нужным и выводит канонический url найденной страницы.

```
function find_template () {
  $my_template = 'my-template.php';
  $args = array (
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'page');
  $posts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    $template = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template');
    if ($template === $my_template) {
        // сказать об этом
        echo wp_get_canonical_url( $post->ID );
    }
  }
}
```